# How to evaluate a call to match.call()?

Tags: r, debugging, evaluation, causality

I'm trying to use a few functions of an R library called "causaldrf". Let's say, inside the library, we have a function "func(a,b)" that takes a string "a" and calls a column named "a" in a dataframe "b".

The function is implemented like this (simplified):

```
func(a,b){
tempcall <- match.call()
Operation then performed on tempcall, for example:
my_string <- tempcall$a 
}
```

Turns out, the match.call() function does not *evaluate* the values of "a" and "b" and rather, takes them as *names*. I find this very annoying because when I write a for loop that reads the value of "a" from a list and call the function "func" inside the for loop, the value of "a" is not used in "func" and rather, tempcall includes *unevaluated names*. This makes the for loop unusable.

I'm wondering, is there a way than can *make the match.call() evaluate* rather than just pass the names?

One solution was to write a wrapper for func() in which I first make a string of func() and its arguments, like, "func(a,b)" and then parse it by parse("func(a,b)") and then evaluate it by eval(parse("func(a,b)")). This way, I could evaluate the values of strings and ints, but the dataframe "b" was passed as a list, which messed it up. I tried passing the dataframe as dataframe by as.dataframe(b) and different types of it, but none worked.

Then, I have used parse(), deparse(), and eval() inside the library in "func" to evaluate match.call(), but none worked.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

P.S. Developers, please don't use match.call() to check for your inputs, it hinders automation.

Comment: Include `print(tempcall$a)` in the function body, it prints the value of the argument. Or have the function return `tempcall$a + tempcall$b`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see your point, but let's say I prefer not to mess up with the source code of the library that I'm using. I'm currently doing so, but I'm getting a huge number of other (expected) errors. This is because "tempcall" and its arguments are used in many many places inside the library. I was wondering if there's a way to go around this without changing the function body?